# Слово, обозначающее определённое поведение

Tags: значение-слов

Много лет назад где-то читал:
Поведение, вынуждающее другого человека выполнять не обязательные (не необходимые, не приводящие к какому-то результату) действия, поступки, называется одним ёмким словом - хамство.
Вопрос: в памяти осталось правильное слово?

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что хамство — это правильное слово к тому, что Вы указали.

Хамство — тип поведения человека, отличающийся грубым, наглым и резким способом общения (бесцеремонностью, цинизмом, вульгарностью, развязностью, бесстыдством, нахальством).

К Вашим характеристикам подойдут, думаю, другие слова: *давление* или *принуждение* (диктат, произвол, деспотизм).
Нужен контекст (или описание конкретной ситуации), чтобы можно было сказать точнее.